# Find first line break and replace

Tags: php

I want this code to find first "`<br>`" tag on a string given and replace with a closing "`</div>`" tag. I can't modify the promo string, so all I can do is modify through the code only. How do I do that? Here is my code:-

```
$promo[$i] = str_replace('<div class="well">','<div class="well"><div class="promo-subTitle">',$promo[$i]);
```

Here is the string based on the variable $promo[$i]:

```
$promo[1] = "<div class="promo"><div class="header">Welcome bonus for you! <br> We have a promo now! <br></div>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$promo[$i] = preg_replace('/<br>/', '</div>', $promo[$i], 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using `preg_replace` function.

```
$promo = '<div class="promo"><div class="header">Welcome bonus for you! <br> We have a promo now! <br></div>';
$promo_out = preg_replace("/<br>/", "</div>", $promo, 1);
```

**Output:**

> HTML

```
<div class="promo"><div class="header">Welcome bonus for you! </div> We have a promo now! <br></div>
```

> Browser:

```
Welcome bonus for you!
We have a promo now!
```

Comment: Good solution too. Thanks!